# React is rerendering my list even though each child in array has its unique key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, as far as I understand react only rerenders new elements with new keys. Thats not working for me though. 
I have a list of posts, that are limited to 3. 
When the user scrolls to bottom of page I add 3 to the limit, which means at the bottom of the page 3 older posts are supposed to be shown. 
What I have now works, but the entire list is being rerendered. And it jumps to the top which is also not wanted (this I can fix though, main problem is the rerendering). They all have unique keys. How can I prevent this behaviour?

```
thisGetsCalledWhenANewPostComesIn(newPost){
    let newPosts = _.clone(this.state.posts);
    newPosts.push(newPost);
    newPosts.sort((a,b) => b.time_posted - a.time_posted); 
    this.setState({posts: newPosts});
}

render(){
     return (
         <div ref={ref => {this.timelineRef = ref;}} style={styles.container}>
             {this.state.posts.map(post =>
                 <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
             )}
         </div>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my bad. I thought I'd only post the "relevant" code, however it turns out, the problem was in the code I left out:

```
    this.setState({posts: []}, ()=> {
        this.postListenerRef = completedPostsRef.orderByChild('time')
        .startAt(newProps.filter.fromDate.getTime())
        .endAt(newProps.filter.toDate.getTime())
        .limitToLast(this.props.filter.postCount)
        .on('child_added', snap => {
            Database.fetchPostFromKey(snap.key)
            .then(post => {             
                let newPosts = _.clone(this.state.posts);
                newPosts.push(_.assign(post, {id: snap.key}));
                newPosts.sort((a,b) => b.time_posted - a.time_posted); 
                this.setState({posts: newPosts});
            }).catch(err => {throw err;});
        });
    });
```

I call `setState({posts: []})` which I am 99% sure is the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Having unique keys alone does not prevent rerendering components that have not changed. Unless you extend [PureComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) or implement [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) for the components, React will have to `render()` the component and compare it to the last result.

### So why do we need [keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) when it's really about `shouldComponentUpdate`?

The purpose of giving each component in a list a unique key is to pass the props to the "right" component instances, so that they can correctly compare new and old props.

Imagine we have a list of items, e.g.:

- A -> componentInstanceA
- B -> componentInstanceB
- C -> componentInstanceC

After applying a filter, the list must be rerendered to show the new list of components, e.g.:

- C -> ?

*Without* proper unique keys, the component that previously rendered `A` will now receive the prop(s) for `C`. Even if `C` is unchanged, the component will have to rerender as it received completely different data:

- C -> componentInstanceA // OH NO!

*With* proper unique keys, the component that rendered `C` will receive `C` again. `shouldComponentUpdate` will then be able to recogize that the render() output will be the same, and the component will not have to rerender:

- C -> componentInstanceC

If your list of items take a long time to render, e.g. if it's a long list or each element is a complex set of data, then you will benefit from preventing unnecessary rerendering.

#### Personal anecdote

In a project with a list of 100s of items which each produced 1000s of DOM elements, changing from

```
list.map((item, index) => <SomeComp key={index} ... />)
```

to

```
list.map(item => <SomeComp key={item.id} ... />)
```

reduced the rendering time by several seconds. Never use array index as key.

Comment: I was just testing `shouldComponentUpdate` and wrote `return false;`. All interaction with the post is now disabled but the entire list is still rerendered when adding to the list. I noticed though that adding one post to the top is fine, adding mutliple posts to the bottom of the list however rerendered all of them. What else could be causing this behaviour? The rerendering takes place in disappearing for a second then returing with the older posts appended to the bottom.

Comment: (1) How long does the initial render take? (2) Is it possible that it takes about a second just to call the `shouldComponentUpdate` of each child? (3) When you talk about adding to the top/bottom of the list, that is after it is sorted, right? (4) How long does it take just to sort the list? (5) Are you running the code currently in the question, or are you running the code that was there before I edited it?

Comment: (1): About twice as long, (2): No, without it they update with the same speed, (3): No, as you can see in my snippet, I push, then sort. But yes, the actualy rendering is after I sort. (4) Sorting only adds a little time. No, its a bit different.

Comment: before you continue, Im pretty sure I found the problem as posted in my anwser. Thanks so much for your effort and the information!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement [shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in the `Post` component. Consider extending the [PureComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) class for the `Post` component instead of the default React `Component`.

Good luck!

---

PS: you can use a string as ref parameter for your div in the render method like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div 
      ref='myRef'
      style={styles.container}
    >
      {this.getPostViews()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, if you want to refer to this element, use it like `this.refs.myRef`. Anyway, this is just a personal preference.

Comment: I'm not too sure what I should check for though. The props will stay the same but I have child components inside `<Post />`  that might update themselves is that fine? Will they continue to update even if my implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns `false`? Must I check each part of newProps if they have changed? PS: Ahh, thats how they work.. thanks for that.